# Decrypt Elliptic-Curve-ElGamal-1024 [cipher,halfmask]) number to text. but it apears unreadble character

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

hi i am working on Elliptic-Curve-ElGamal-1024 [cipher,halfmask]) . it works fine decrypt into number ,but it runs into error after cover into ASCII 256
and here is the info
prime = 111697039144439244274158398653562346085125490793664062732425069223685968110844126905903321206114392849452542256992315754843167574112467024858088205347572299296687223643952822745811271693456632679803618511515217807199664219990752590959138703164100104061985978987701427311881250925416668035932094333108552446839

Elliptic Curve parameters (Weierstrass form):
A = 150670258656281464005027759708221023233910114637886003539106738481215882957713483236742237072518545883429463829128035822122070539009268529588117340272238455156286895193960706935802180341819752120102766312902122204702353872155278694417075931419847141024333493817900461006527055261695842425790546228916431325513
B = 104815861020657080241596578752393940140617569980803135496881290764938288013364134928068097698824115341484980977151298278192209798477977140363086488236483224661104202521225088803004668319349969513561776896401494842782206897897856458042025648888304723359320219472250799841670786377536581380629352855788742594142

Generator = [61643059794514658855856979240384380792004005595902002474204661739186732752684754456411382735922901235495907950404348644170841371014778432355106487961684475960234463142352681608311501007071362596770681949544839546671743458092267656460600660256785359231219517003730759173037578221710970121586110683785072217662,54359302960000760545008891946403739583148786728166654515466055048776801978921702648886655754375020415206500780463313877521057493281570465893562576850601434219889617981357296583120996241733031701559848144381511290881538520012299210485219015267103348638818685963120393173867173336217274772249726418109868176493]

Public Point = [60949449667193749252503359889850425121315508973346945821886368823756771832998966289937779780434994149115196710111811694044123631896909518754733352427887648092521748310305738624343577584577041608478447076368817057789725108338375345629371222211045251384720803595793058052264980931562187712908832419030905731456,61732224616283043648568020304215677416953487728868336147524271976573117696218390316816254546008953094848938572310947651922118368895678399666836335369620907736296238282509607980572392998672197795698218685116119057168223625468009549912498255285830874111241719004852772790800875392292105908437344598596511413453]

Secret Multiplier = smallest prime that is not the oddest one

and here is my code

```
import sys

def inverse_mod(a, m):
    if a < 0 or m <= a:
        a = a % m
    c, d = a, m
    uc, vc, ud, vd = 1, 0, 0, 1
    while c != 0:
        q, c, d = divmod(d, c) + (c,)
        uc, vc, ud, vd = ud - q * uc, vd - q * vc, uc, vc
    assert d == 1
    if ud > 0:
        return ud
    else:
        return ud + m

def add_points(P, Q, prime, A):
    if P == (0, 0):
        return Q
    if Q == (0, 0):
        return P

    x1, y1 = P
    x2, y2 = Q

    if x1 == x2:
        if (y1 + y2) % prime == 0:
            return 0, 0
        else:
            lam = (3 * x1 ** 2 + A) * inverse_mod(2 * y1, prime) % prime
    else:
        lam = (y2 - y1) * inverse_mod(x2 - x1, prime) % prime

    x3 = (lam ** 2 - x1 - x2) % prime
    y3 = (lam * (x1 - x3) - y1) % prime

    return x3, y3
# def int_to_ascii_chars(value):
#     hex_str = hex(value)[2:]
#     if len(hex_str) % 2 == 1:
#         hex_str = '0' + hex_str
#     bytes_list = [int(hex_str[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(hex_str), 2)]
#     return ''.join(chr(b) for b in bytes_list)
def int_to_ascii_chars(value):
    if 32 <= value <= 126:
        return chr(value)
    else:
        return '?'


def multiply(n, P, prime, A, B):
    result = (0, 0)
    temp = P
    while n:
        if n & 1:
            result = add_points(result, temp, prime, A)
        temp = add_points(temp, temp, prime, A)
        n >>= 1
    return result

def addDif(x1, y1, x2, y2, prime, A):
    return add_points((x1, y1), (x2, -y2 % prime), prime, A)

prime = 111697039144439244274158398653562346085125490793664062732425069223685968110844126905903321206114392849452542256992315754843167574112467024858088205347572299296687223643952822745811271693456632679803618511515217807199664219990752590959138703164100104061985978987701427311881250925416668035932094333108552446839
A = 150670258656281464005027759708221023233910114637886003539106738481215882957713483236742237072518545883429463829128035822122070539009268529588117340272238455156286895193960706935802180341819752120102766312902122204702353872155278694417075931419847141024333493817900461006527055261695842425790546228916431325513
B = 104815861020657080241596578752393940140617569980803135496881290764938288013364134928068097698824115341484980977151298278192209798477977140363086488236483224661104202521225088803004668319349969513561776896401494842782206897897856458042025648888304723359320219472250799841670786377536581380629352855788742594142
Generator = [61643059794514658855856979240384380792004005595902002474204661739186732752684754456411382735922901235495907950404348644170841371014778432355106487961684475960234463142352681608311501007071362596770681949544839546671743458092267656460600660256785359231219517003730759173037578221710970121586110683785072217662, 54359302960000760545008891946403739583148786728166654515466055048776801978921702648886655754375020415206500780463313877521057493281570465893562576850601434219889617981357296583120996241733031701559848144381511290881538520012299210485219015267103348638818685963120393173867173336217274772249726418109868176493]
public_point = [60949449667193749252503359889850425121315508973346945821886368823756771832998966289937779780434994149115196710111811694044123631896909518754733352427887648092521748310305738624343577584577041608478447076368817057789725108338375345629371222211045251384720803595793058052264980931562187712908832419030905731456, 61732224616283043648568020304215677416953487728868336147524271976573117696218390316816254546008953094848938572310947651922118368895678399666836335369620907736296238282509607980572392998672197795698218685116119057168223625468009549912498255285830874111241719004852772790800875392292105908437344598596511413453]
secret_multiplier = 2
q = prime
a = A
n = secret_multiplier

# Read cipher from file
cipher = []
with open("cipher.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        buff = line.split()
        buff = [int(i) for i in buff]
        cipher.append([(buff[0], buff[1]), (buff[2], buff[3])])

text = []

for i in cipher:
    c = i[0]
    h = i[1]

    x, y = multiply(n, h, q, a, B)

    f = (x, q-y)
    m = addDif(f[0], f[1], c[0], c[1], q, A)
    text.append(int_to_ascii_chars(m[0]))


# Write decrypted text to file
with open("decrypted.txt", "w") as file:
    for t in text:
        file.write(str(t) + "\n")
```

hi i am working on Elliptic-Curve-ElGamal-1024 [cipher,halfmask]) . it works fine decrypt into number ,but it runs into error after cover into ASCII 256. can anyone help me figuers whats going on.